# Get average of count by group

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have the following data:

```
Id          SiteId          Converted
--          ------          ---------
1           1               TRUE
2           1               FALSE
3           1               TRUE
4           2               TRUE
5           3               FALSE
6           3               TRUE
```

How can I get the **Average Count of Converted by SiteId**

The count per site would be:

```
SiteId          Count
------          -----
1               3
2               1
3               2
```

And the end result I want is:

```
Converted   Average
---------   -------
TRUE        1.33 (4 converted / 3 sites)
FALSE       0.67 (2 not converted / 3 sites)
```

I tried using a pivot table for this and can get the overall count but not the average. If I could group by SiteId, Count of each group, then average the counts it would give me the desired result but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Break it into two separate problems:

1. How many `Converted` values are TRUE? How many are FALSE?
2. How many unique `SiteId` values are there?

The first problem is easy:

```
Count of TRUE =COUNTIF(C:C,TRUE)
Count of FALSE =COUNTIF(C:C,FALSE)
```

The second problem is trickier but still well-known: (This assumes all your `SiteId` values are numeric. If they're not, refer to [this Office help page](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273#bmcount_the_number_of_unique_values_by_) for alternatives.)

```
Count of unique SiteID values =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(B:B,B:B)>0,1))
```

Now, all you have to do is combine them.

```
TRUE    =COUNTIF(C:C,TRUE)/SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(B:B,B:B)>0,1))
FALSE   =COUNTIF(C:C,FALSE)/SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(B:B,B:B)>0,1))
```